# Docker/Symfony/PhpUnit - No logs displaying in console when running PhpUnit in container

Tags: php, docker, symfony, dockerfile, phpunit

I don't have logs when running `bin/phpunit` on the console in my `web` container.

**My web dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        sudo \
        unzip \
        zip \
        git \
        nano \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql opcache \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY ./apache/chat-app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
RUN "date"

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!/var/www!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!/var/www!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
```

When i run phpunit:
[image: screenshot]

What's wrong ?

I've tried to add xdebug but it's also not working.
I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and I use Tilix console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I removed `symfony/phpunit-bridge` package and use `phpunit/phpunit` instead.

```
composer remove --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

Now, logs are displaying on the console in my `web` container.

[image: screenshot2]